# Google app engine and application scope data

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm developing a spring based web application that is deployed on Google app Engine.
I have a manager that store data in application scope. I'm using a spring bean (singleton) that hold a map and simply perform get and remove from the map,
 however GAE is a distributed environment and this design has a problem since each application instance will have its own manager and request are not guaranteed to be made to the same application instance.
So I've looked around and found 2 possible solution:

1. use data store
2. use memcache

storing the data will cause a lot of read and writes and eventually I do not need the data to be saved.
second looked promising but Google mentioned  that:

> **In general, an application should not expect a cached value to always be available.**

and I need a guarantee that when I ask my manger to get a value it will return it.

is there any other solution?
did I miss anything?

Comment: What sort of data is this? How much of it? How often will it change?

Comment: it's a multiplayers game map, each element is a game that hold state for all players in that game (up to 5 players). the data is fetch frequently, every second or so, and update every 5 seconds or so. in terms of size it is not big, at max it will be less than 1MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common solution is storing the values in a memcache, backed by the datastore.

First fetch the application-scope value from the memcache, and if the memcache returns zero-result (a cache-miss event), fetch the value from the datastore and put the fetched value on the memcache.

In this way, the next fetch to the memcache would return your application-scope data, reducing the need for a (relatively) costly read to the datastore.

App Engine memcache is a least-recently used cache, so values that are frequently read would suffer from few cache-miss event.

A more complex solution to have a application-scope value is to store the values in-memory at a resident backend, and have all your other instances request/update the value from/to this particular backend via a servlet handler.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it helps then? Click the dotted check mark on the left side of an answer if you want to accept it. It will turn into a green check mark then.